# How can I debug J2V8/node.js when running within JVM?

Tags: node.js, v8, j2v8

Typically, I use node inspector (https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to debug node.js. Can this be used to attach to a remote node.js instance running in the JVM via J2V8?

Also, it looks like the dev version of node.js supports native Chrome debugging: https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/6792. If J2V8 adopts this version of node.js, will I be able to simply attach the Chrome debugger directly to the JVM?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is still relevant - I have created [j2v8-debugger](https://github.com/AlexTrotsenko/j2v8-debugger) library.

It allows debugging `J2V8` using Chrome DevTools.

Basic features like setting/removing breakpoints, step into, step out and step over, variables inspection, etc. are implemented.

It uses *Stetho* lib for communication with *Chrome DevTools*.

Also it's uses *DebugHandler* for accessing *V8* debug information.

If you need need to debug J2V8, which runs on non-Android JVM you would need to use another lib for communication to Chrome DevTools, but likely you could re-use all the logic from this project as it's basically POJO/JSON, which are send over web socket.

Hope it could be helpful.