# How to debug J2V8 in Android with chrome developer tools?

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, v8, stetho, j2v8

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660656/how-can-i-debug-j2v8-node-js-when-running-within-jvm) has been asked before, but had no traction. Clearly, [it is possible](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2016/06/06/debugging-javascript-with-tabris-js/) but it is by no means clear how to do it in our own non-tabris Android app.

The best documentation we have on the matter is [this commit](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/commit/6451567ac93e1fba7335f167bd42eb8e57af18a8), but I tried `V8.setFlags("--expose-debug-as=Debug");` as well as `V8.setFlags("--expose-debug-as=" + DebugHandler.DEBUG_OBJECT_NAME);` but no debuggable app appeared in chrome developer tools.

I even tried in combo with enabling Stetho and in that case I was able to debug the app, but there was no javascript source to debug. I believe that I'm close but missing one small crucial nugget.

Answer (score 1):

The article that you link to states that they implemented it in their product using the [Stetho library](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) to provide the Chrome Dev Tools debugger protocol support.
Therefore you would need to use the [DebugAPI class](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/blob/master/src/main/java/com/eclipsesource/v8/debug/DebugHandler.java) and expose that to DevTools via the Chrome debug bridge protocol, though at first glance I can't see how to use Stetho to expose the debug api.

The tests in the j2v8 codebase do provide a [good example of how to use the DebugAPI](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/blob/master/src/test/java/com/eclipsesource/v8/debug/ScriptBreakPointTest.java)

Answer (score 1):

If the question is still relevant - I have created [j2v8-debugger](https://github.com/AlexTrotsenko/j2v8-debugger) library.

It allows debugging `J2V8` using Chrome DevTools.

It indeed uses *Stetho* lib for communication with *Chrome DevTools*.

Also it's uses *DebugHandler* for accessing *V8* debug information.

Basic features like setting/removing breakpoints, step into, step out and step over, variables inspection, etc. are implemented.

Hope it could be helpful.